# Scan SVN folder using HPE Static Code Analyzer

Tags: svn, code-analysis, fortify

I have a situation where i need to create a **schedule for HP static code analyzer** to **scan a specific folder on SVN server daily**. If it is possible how to set up?

Answer (score 0):

I feel the scripts can be generated to perform Fortify Analysis and scheduled to run at the required frequency.

The Scan Wizard tool in SCA can help with building a script required for analysis of a specific project. Appendix F (HPE SSC 16.20) in the SCA User Guide has more details.

The generated script can be further customized for implementation-specific needs.

I hope it will work for you.